# How to say "please enter your name"?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

For context, I'm creating a website form that requests the user's name. A direct translation of the phrase would be something like

> Veuillez entrer votre nom

but I've heard that "saisir" can be used when referring to data entry. Would

> Veuillez saisir votre nom

make any sense? Or is there a completely different option that would be more correct?

Comment: You also have "Veuillez renseigner votre nom", just in case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are both absolutely correct and both mean:

> Please enter your name.

However for a website I would rather use:

> Veuillez saisir votre nom.

---

It is also usual to simply see:

> Nom

As you can see on the [Google register page](https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount&hl=fr&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp):

[image]

Comment: As a sidenote, Google is a specific case because they rely on their Material UI design, which advises to use short sentences (or only words) to describe the inputs and buttons.

Comment: Well by having myself strong knowledge about web development, I can assure you Google register page isn't specific, but more a nowaday-standard.

Comment: You're being confused : it's not a standard, it's a design guildeline. I'm not saying only a few people do that : I'm saying that in the case of Google, it's because of their Material Design. Sure, it's done by a lot of people. But it's not a standard at all ! In case you doubt it, [here are the guildelines for Material texts](https://material.io/design/communication/writing.html#principles).

Comment: Of course, I agree with you so :) Interesting link btw.

Answer (score 2):

Both "entrer" and "saisir" are correct.